# Only Create Table when it has rows of data

Tags: html, html-table, mustache

If I have a simple table:

```
<table>
<TR><TH>First Name</TH><TH>Last Name</TH></TR>
<TR><TD>John</TD><TD>Smith</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Sponge</TD><TD>Bob</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

I can load it in MustacheJS with something like:

```
<Table>
<TR><TH>First Name</TH><TH>Last Name</TH></TR>
{{#loop}}
<TR><TD>{{fname}}</TD><TD>{{lname}}</TD></TR>
{{/loop}}
</TABLE>
```

And it works properly with data in the format of:

```
{ loop: [{fname:"John", lname:"Smith"},{fname:"Sponge", lname:"Bob"}]}
```

But how do the same thing but ONLY have the table show at all if there are rows of data? If I move the #loop to surround the table, it creates multiple tables per row.

Comment: use Inverted-Sections: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#inverted-sections {{^loop}}

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how you can get rid of the <table> with inverted selectors. I do understand how I can use an inverted selector to display a different row of data, e.g. a row which says, "No data". If there is a way to use them to hide the top of the table, I don't understand how to do that and I'll need a little bit more of an explanation.

Comment: You can try and maintain another variable based on the length of loop, and use it to hide/show the table maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an additional property to your data that will return a boolean based on the length of your data to loop. Then add a section to your template to display the table based on this new property.

Data:

```js
var data = {
  loop: [
    { fname: "John", lname: "Smith" },
    { fname: "Sponge", lname: "Bob" }
  ],
  shouldLoop() { return this.loop.length > 0 }
};
```

Template:

```html
{{#shouldLoop}}
<Table>
<TR><TH>First Name</TH><TH>Last Name</TH></TR>
{{#loop}}
<TR><TD>{{fname}}</TD><TD>{{lname}}</TD></TR>
{{/loop}}
</TABLE>
{{/shouldLoop}}
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than what I had ended up hacking together. Thanks for this!

Comment: In MustacheJS and *some* other implementations, you could also do `{{#loop.length}}<table>...</table>{{/loop.length}}` instead. This answer is arguably more portable, though.